# Does eclipse currently have a better way to show multiple tab rows?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does Eclipse has a better way to support multiple tab rows now? I use Intellij before and use eclipse now, I don't know why such a long time eclipse still doesn't have an better to show many tabs.

I use eclipse Luna now and I know there is a plugin "Editors List" which can show many tabs vertically, really cool. However this tool doesn't sync tab to file very well, not very easy to use.

And don't really want to click "ctrl+e" every time to see all tabs.

Is there a better way to display all tabs in eclipse(Just like what Intellij does) or give me more suggestion?

Thank you so much!

Comment: As far as I know unless you want to download an external plugin you're kind of stuck with it. :/

Comment: yeah, besides "Editors List", will you recommend something else?

Comment: I can't say I've ever used anything sorry :/ However I might recommend you look on the programming reddit or maybe SO meta or maybe the computer sciece Stack Exchange. I don't browse those communities much but you might see some similar searches in the community!

Comment: Try this plugin [Extended VS Presentation plugin for Eclipse](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html)